# Spring 3.1 Hibernate 4 not rolling back JDBC transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, rollback, jdbctemplate

I am having trouble setting up a JUnit test that will rollback. I've read a few of these posts here on SO before deciding to write a question, as none seems to be the answer to my problem.

The second test case is failing because data is inserted and persisted in DB from the first test case.

Here's the JUnit test:

```
package com.company.group.spring.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.company.group.spring.model.BusObj;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:NAME_OF_CONFIG_FILE.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager", defaultRollback = true)
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class}) 
public class PerPartsWCDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myBusObjDAO")
    private BusObjDAO busObj_dao;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void testInsertRollback() {
        try {
        BusObj busObj = new BusObj("some data...");

        assertNotNull(busObj_dao);
        assertNotNull(busObj);

        busObj_dao.insert(perPartWC);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    @Rollback(false)
    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
        BusObj busObj2 = new BusObj("some data...");

        busObj_dao.insert(perPartWC2);
    }

}
```

Here's the DAOImpl class (the class I'm trying to test):

```
package com.company.group.spring.dao;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.company.group.spring.model.BusObj;

@Repository("myBusObjDAO")
public class myBusObjDAOImpl implements myBusObjDAO {

private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Override
public void insert(BusObj someObj) {
    String sql = "insert into TABLE (args...) " +
            "VALUES (:named_params....)";

    SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(someObj);

    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource);
}
```

}

Part of the relevant config:

```
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />


  <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER:PORT:DB"/>
      <property name="username" value="USER"/>
      <property name="password" value="XXXXXX"/>

  </bean>
```

Edit: +debug print

```
2012-12-18 08:50:42,177 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction()] Creating new transaction with name [com.company.group.spring.service.MyClassService.create]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT

2012-12-18 08:50:42,342 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin()] Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction

2012-12-18 08:50:42,344 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin()] Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]

2012-12-18 08:50:42,361 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin()] Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler@128647a[valid=true]]

2012-12-18 08:50:42,390 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update()] Executing prepared SQL update

2012-12-18 08:50:42,391 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute()] Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into TABLE (args...) VALUES (?, ?, SYSDATE,?, ?, SYSDATE, ?,?, ?)]

2012-12-18 08:50:42,391 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection()] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

2012-12-18 08:50:42,657 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection()] Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection

2012-12-18 08:50:42,671 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement()] SQL update affected 1 rows

2012-12-18 08:50:42,678 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection()] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

2012-12-18 08:50:42,688 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback()] Initiating transaction rollback

2012-12-18 08:50:42,688 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback()] Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]

2012-12-18 08:50:42,693 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion()] Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
```

Update:
I noticed in the log, it is trying to rollback a Hibernate transaction (but this is JDBC). Then noticed the class for "txManager" is currently **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager**, so I experimented with **org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager** and *voila*, rollback worked. So I think my problem is more specifically how I'm configuring to use Hibernate and JDBC... I still don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Here's the relevant (I think) debug log... let me know if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was specifying the dataSource for the HibernateTransactionManager. Here's the documentation on [HibernateTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html).

So I guess it was a mistake not posting how I defined the `txManager` in the original post.

```
  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```

Changed to:

```
  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>
```

I also added `<property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>` to the SessionFactory definition, but it doesn't seem necessary if I'm only worried about JdbcTemplate.  Suspect it's needed though if HQL is intermixed in there.

Here's what the debug print looks like when it is working. The only difference I saw was this line `Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource` was absent before initiate rollback

```
2012-12-19 08:14:29,455 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction()] Creating new transaction with name [com.company.group.spring.service.MyClassService.create]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''

2012-12-19 08:14:29,512 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin()] Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction

2012-12-19 08:14:29,514 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin()] Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]

2012-12-19 08:14:29,539 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin()] Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler@1289e48[valid=true]]

2012-12-19 08:14:29,558 [main] DEBUG [com.company.group.spring.dao.MyClassDAOImpl.insert()] Session Factory is: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@1285252

2012-12-19 08:14:29,569 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update()] Executing prepared SQL update

2012-12-19 08:14:29,570 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute()] Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into MY_CLASS (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9) VALUES (?, ?, SYSDATE,?, ?, SYSDATE, ?,?, ?)]

2012-12-19 08:14:29,608 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement()] SQL update affected 1 rows

2012-12-19 08:14:29,611 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback()] Initiating transaction rollback

2012-12-19 08:14:29,612 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback()] Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]

2012-12-19 08:14:29,680 [main] DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion()] Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JUnit and DAO classes looks fine.

The problem might be that the connection is auto-committing before the transaction is rolled back. Can you change the dataSource bean to include a *defaultAutoCommit* property

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER:PORT:DB"/>
      <property name="username" value="USER"/>
      <property name="password" value="XXXXXX"/>
      <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" /> 
</bean>
```

If this is not working can you paste your console logs.

Comment: I've tried that, but none of the inserts are ever committed.  I suspect that is moving away from declarative transactions if I have to programatically call commit... I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Plus, looks like it's pretty invasive and binds us to Spring if I understood it correctly. Thinking of section 11.6 [http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)